# How to change color code in a script

Tags: javascript, php

Hi guys i want to change this line
    $("#Tcounter").css("color","red");
in this script with a color code #BC0202, how do i need to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
    var Tcharacters = <?php echo $max_character_length_title; ?>;
        $("#Tcounter").append("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Tcharacters+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
        $("#title<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > Tcharacters){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, Tcharacters));
        }
    var Tremaining = Tcharacters -  $(this).val().length;
        $("#Tcounter").html("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Tremaining+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
    if(Tremaining <= 10)
    {
        $("#Tcounter").css("color","red");
        }
    else
    {
        $("#Tcounter").css("color","black");
        }
    });

    var Dcharacters = <?php echo $max_character_length_description; ?>;
        $("#Dcounter").append("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Dcharacters+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
        $("#description<?php echo osc_current_user_locale(); ?>").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > Dcharacters){
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, Dcharacters));
    }
    var Dremaining = Dcharacters -  $(this).val().length;
        $("#Dcounter").html("<small><?php osc_esc_js(_e('You have','ctg_housing')); ?> <strong>"+  Dremaining+"</strong> <?php osc_esc_js(_e('characters remaining','ctg_housing')); ?></small>");
    if(Dremaining <= 10)
    {
        $("#Dcounter").css("color","red");
        }
    else
    {
        $("#Dcounter").css("color","black");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

More information about this i cant give!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: If i change this with "#BC0202" it still stay the old color!

Comment: I understand that... Do you have any errors displaying in the browser console?

Comment: No any error displays

Comment: I would also suggest you tag `jQuery` to your question since this script is using the **jQuery plug-in**

Answer (score 2):

Simple, change `red` to `#BC0202`

```js
$("#Tcounter").css("color","#BC0202");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Tcounter">Foobar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **Replace** color *name* with corresponding *hex code* of that of color.

Comment: if i do this $("#Dcounter").css("color","#BC0202");i receive stil the red color

Comment: Yea, as this hex code belongs to strong red color, it will reflect that.